# restore.php error

Tags: битрикс

Зашел в админку сайта и создал резервную копию, скачал ее на комп, тут же скачал restore.php, скофигурировал апач, закинул рестор в папку с сайтом, открыл в браузере localhost/restore.php, выбрал пункт "загрузить с локального диска", указал путь к скаченному бекапу .tar.gz, и получаю ошибку: 
Не удалось открыть файл: File is a directory 
Менял права на папку, переносил бекап - ничего не помогает.

Как вообще, при указании на на архив, можно получить ошибку, что данный файл - директория ? 
Помогите ребят, я уже не знаю, что и делать.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно или положить архив рядом с файлом restore.php или загрузить файл через стандартную загрузку файла.

Сервер просто не видит ту папку которую вы указываете

Comment: restore.php и бекап лежат в одной папке с максимальными правами и все такое. А вот что за стандартная загрузка файла я не понял)